# WordPress Dashboard Showing Pure HTML and 404 Error When Editing Website: Need Help Resolving Issue

Tags: php, html, wordpress, error-handling, wordpress-theming

### The Issue

I opened WordPress today to work on my website, but I encountered a problem where my WordPress dashboard appears in pure  `HTML` and is unresponsive. Clicking the **"home"** link leads me to my home page with an `error 404` message. Strangely, when accessing the website as a customer, it works perfectly fine, and the site is up and running. However, I am unable to edit my website due to this issue. I did not make any changes or edits that could have caused this problem. I'm a beginner and do not know how to access the files or use `PHP`. Can anyone help me resolve this issue so that I can regain access to my WordPress dashboard and edit my website? Is this a Wordpress server error? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here's what it looks like:

### **WP-Dashboard:**

[image: WP-dashboard Pure HTML]

### **Error on my Site**

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the devtools console?

Comment: No, where is that?

Comment: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch002153.htm

Comment: Thank you my brother, however i recently figured out that it was malware haha. Appreciate your help!